# Can I copy the nuget package configuration from one project to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

If I have one project in VS2010 for which I have added a number of packages using nuget, can I then create another project in that solution and somehow obtain the exact same package configuration?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but I decided to share how I am doing this to anyone looking for the same:

1. Drag & drop the `packages.config` from the project where the packages are already installed to the new project.
2. Open the Package Manager Console
3. Type:

   ```
   Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName [name of your target project]
   ```

Comment: well done for answering the question rather than answering some question that wasn't asked.

Comment: Note: If you want to get all the references and not just installed packages this method will miss the extra references that aren't part of a package. For example Solution references. I guess these will need adding manually by comparing the "References" list of both projects.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to install the assembly binding redirects in your app.config, at least in some cases. If you're depending on those for some reason, reinstalling the individual package seems to fix it. Might just be a bug in Nuget.

Comment: I used the "Manage" option in Manage NuGet Packages dialog and it worked for me.  You can tell it to install for more than one project.

Answer (score 22):

You can right click on solution node and select "Manage packages for solution" then you will  see a list of installed packages in the solution ,by selecting each package and clicking "Manage" button you can say which package belongs to which project.

Comment: Although gjsduarte's answer answers the original question better I have up voted this as well as I found it was quite useful information to share.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio - open both projects ( .csproj files ). Copy the `<ItemGroup>` containing the `<PackageReference />` definitions. Save the target project.