# Nuget package copy across projects

Tags: .net-core

[Is Nuget package copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11026137/1431250) feasible in .Net Core?
I'm worried since, there is neither project.json nor package.config. Does it mean manually editing .csproj is the only way to go forward.

There has to be more efficient way, IMHO. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a shared `Directory.Build.props` file to build same packages across multiple projects for .NET Core 2.0. So if you put this file in a shared folder for all your projects and simply import it after you create a new project, it does save a lot of time.

First create a shared `Directory.Build.props` file. Below I am adding NLog package for all my projects. Sample content for file:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.5.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now import this file to root of your projects by right clicking the project 1 > Add > Existing Item > Directory.Build.props. Repeat the same for your other projects; project 2, project 3, etc. Notice that when you add the file each to your projects; NLog packages from Directory.Build.props file is automatically added as Nuget package.

Simply edit the XML and more package references under `<ItemGroup></ItemGroup>` for your packages. I hope this will be more efficient solution for you. It certainly saves me lot of time for new .NET Core projects. You can read more about customising build [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build).

Comment: You don't need to import this for every project.  The build process will walk the parent directories looking for it. Just put it in a common parent directory and all other projects in the sub-directories below will inherit it. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#search-scope)