# Is there a way to copy nuget package references from one solution to another in .net-core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im currently migrating some projects from asp.net to asp.net-core and have a template asp.net-core solution which i use model for all the other applications. 
As the template projects includes all the neccessary nuget-packages for this transition, I tried to find a way to copy my nuget configuration from one this project to another.
Sadly, I couldnt find a way in .net-core to approach this wish.

I searched for a lot of ways in visual studio and online on how to do this, but couldn't find a way. In .net it was possible to copy the packages.config file into another Project as explained in this post:

[Can I copy the nuget package configuration from one project to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026137/can-i-copy-the-nuget-package-configuration-from-one-project-to-another)

There is no packages.config in .net-core anymore however.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? It would really save a lot of time not having to install 20+ packages manually for every project I am working on.

Comment: Migrate package.config to package reference Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Comment: I assume you mean how to copy references to packages in the Package Reference format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files To do that, you just have to copy all <PackageReference> nodes in the csproj file to the new csproj file.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea - Add that as the answer

Comment: @AlexandruClontea Thanks for your quick answer that was the trick ... I tried this before and it did not compile however. Any information why this could fail?

Comment: Many possible reasons: bad edit/broken format, different netcore versions, even the occasional nuget outage, nuget caching,, etc. Tough to know without a compile error's message. You can always post another question if you encounter issues again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just copy the PackageReference nodes you need to the new project. Source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Some interesting reads: [What are package references and how will they help me optimise the way I deal with Nuget packages](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15293/what-are-packagereferences-and-how-will-they-help-optimise-the-way-i-deal-with-n) and [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Comment: Like @AlexandruClonțea mentioned adding the ``<PackageReference>`` nodes into your .csproj file does the trick.